# Eclipse, C++ and "Debugging Assistants"?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, diagnostics

Visual Studio has [Managed Debugging Assistants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163606.aspx) (MDAs) and Xcode has [Application Diagnostics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeDiagnostics.html) which can be enabled on a scheme.

I'm specifically interested in "value added" debugging and diagnostics provided by Eclipse or a plug-in. I only found [org.eclipse.cdt.debug.ui.memory](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/junosr1) on the Eclipse website, and it only provides "memory renderings"; I could *not* find {Eclipse+Mudflap} and {Eclipse+Dmalloc} when searching. I'm either missing something, or Eclipse does not offer aides to the developer.

Does Eclipse have anything to help with the development and debugging experience?

Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least for development for QNX under Eclipse there exists a detailed introduction to the usage of Mudflap:

http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.4.1/ide_en/user_guide/debug.html#UsingMudflapInIDE